# Draw a rectangle with x,y bottom and top coordinates

Tags: python, opencv

I have coordinates defined as:

```
tl = (result['topleft']['x'], result['topleft']['y'])
br = (result['bottomright']['x'], result['bottomright']['y'])
```

And I would like to draw a rectangle around the object of interest, using OpenCv; I tried with:

```
cv2.rectangle(img, (tl[0], tl[1]), ( tl[0]-br[1], tl[1]-br[0] ), (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

But it does not include the object. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `cv2.rectangle()` in the wrong format. It should be

```
cv2.rectangle(img, tl, br, (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

Here is what the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html) says:

```
cv.Rectangle(img, pt1, pt2, color, thickness=1, lineType=8, shift=0)
```

where `pt1` and `pt2` should be opposite vertex coordinates.

Comment: and in this context, central region coordinates x and y are tl[0] and tl[1]?

Comment: `tl` (tl[0], tl[1]) is the coordinate of the topleft vertex.